# Google Analytics and Subresource Integrity

Tags: security, google-analytics, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

I have *Subresource Integrity* (SRI) enabled in the *Content Security Policy* (CSP) headers.

How can I integrate google analytics? Using a hash for their script will probably break within a few days when google updates their analytics-javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. This affects anyone using payment processors like Google Pay or Braintree as well. Pretty serious for PCI compliance.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any word from Google on this. Since their libraries and services are so popular and their own Chrome browser is now stepping up support for these security measures it's a shame they are not more on top of getting a way to make SRI work for their CSS and JavaScript components.

Comment: They added CORS support for GTM in 2020 according to [this thread](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/15985818?hl=en), so perhaps they've done the same now for GA.